# Set MaxReceivedMessageSize (The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request.) web.config doesn't work

Tags: wcf

I had been working on this error for a week and still can't solve it after searching.
The error is:

> The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad
>   Request.

I try to save a image from Windows phone app through WCF and I know that I need to set the `MaxReceivedMessageSize` higher than the default! I had try everything but no luck!

My `web.config` file (wcf services)

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:10"
                sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                openTimeout="00:10:00"
                closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                transferMode="Buffered"
                messageEncoding="Text"
                textEncoding="utf-8"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true" >
          <readerQuotas
             maxDepth="2147483647"
             maxStringContentLength="2147483646"
             maxArrayLength="2147483647"
             maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
             maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
   <services>
     <service name="Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior">
       <endpoint
          address=""
         binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"  
          contract="IService1" />
        <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange"
        />
     </service>
   </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

On my Windows phone application only have the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig`

```
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
         <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
               <security mode="None" />
            </binding>
         </basicHttpBinding>
       </bindings>
       <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1772/Service1.svc" 
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" 
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
       </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I also try to set the binding in code:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;

EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:1772/Service1.svc");

Service1Client  proxy = new Service1Client(binding, endpointAddress);
```

I really don't know how to fix this... it look like the server didn't use my web.config file??? If that the case how do I update it?

Answer (score 0):

You must verify this is really the issue. For start turn on WCF trace on the server ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx ) and see what error is there.

Comment: I can upload small image (under 65kb)

Comment: there are many quota settings. if you can turn on the server trace you will find out exactly which one it complains on.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems OK at first glance - except I had a hunch maybe your service config isn't being picked up because your service name is odd....

You have:

```
 <service name="Service1" >
```

Is your service class - the one implementing the service contract - really called just `Service1` and doesn't exist inside any namespaces??

The value of the `name=` attribute on the `<service>` node **must be** exactly the **fully-qualified** name of the type of your service class - so most likely, it would be something like this:

```
 <service name="MyNamespace.Service1" >
```

or whatever **.NET namespace** your `Service1` class lives in

If that name doesn't match, then the WCF runtime will **not use** that service config and fall back to the WCF defaults, which would explain why it works for smaller files - but fails for larger ones.

Comment: The name is Service1 my Project name(namespace) is InstantMessengerWebService, When i change the <service name ="Service1" to InstantMessengerWebService.Service1 i can't even run the server, (can't run the service1.scv.cs)

Comment: @TuanPham: if you change to `<service name="InstantMessengerWebService.Service1">...` - what happens? Do you get an error?? If so : **what** error???